# KnockoutJS, mapping plugin, get notified when changes in model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Im using knockoutJS in following way:

```
var messagesFromServer = getJSONData().messages; //this get msgs from server
ko.mapping.fromJS(messagesFromServer, {}, myobject.viewModel.Messages);
```

Then i am basically calling this every three seconds to update html table, and it works just fine, new rows are added if new data found from server. Now i would like to add custom callback when something has actually changed, for example when new messages are found.

How should i implement this?

thanks in adv,

-hk

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the two objects into json, then compare them json strings.

```
var messagesFromServer = getJSONData().messages; //this get msgs from server
var newString = ko.toJSON(messagesFromServer);
var oldString = ko.toJSON(myobject.viewModel.Messages);
if(newString != oldString ) {
 // something new
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(messagesFromServer, {}, myobject.viewModel.Messages);
```

[See ko.toJSON doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the `messages` is array, you can use `ko.utils.compareArrays` to detect the changes and raise custom events yourself. Here is code example for comparing `ko.observableArray()`. Look for [Comparing two arrays](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)